# Two Dimensional Array Representing a Weight Matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, tree

I'm a bit stumped in how a 2d array(Matrix) such as this

```
0.0  1.8  9.1  4.0  3.5 

1.8  0.0  8.1  5.2  8.6 

9.1  8.1  0.0  2.9  8.1 

4.0  5.2  2.9  0.0  2.0 

3.5  8.6  8.1  2.0  0.0
```

is supposed to represent a graph. The values represent the weights but then what represents the nodes and edges. I'm trying to brute force find all possible tree's (Which I'm not asking for help on that, just trying to understand how this is supposed to represent this [image]

Comment: If you don't know, how do you expect anyone to? This is just a matrix of numbers. There is no universal convention for interpreting a 2D matrix of numbers as some kind of a graph. There's nothing else to go on.

Comment: If you have static topology then you just need to define an order for serialization/deserialization, otherwise what you ask is impossible if not including some metadata for the graph topology.

Comment: The only thing I have to go off is "For an algorithm that operates on a weight matrix, it takes the weight matrix
stored in a two-dimensional array as its parameter"

Comment: Your data does not make any sense at all. It could have meant that Row 0 is node 0, and it has 0.0 cost to itself, 1.8 cost to Node1, 4.0 cost to Node 2 .. etc (Hence the diagonal 0.0s in your table). But it is not the case with your data since you have only 5 lines (5 nodes - graph has 8), and each node has three edges with some neighbors(Does not match your graph as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a (weighted, undirected) graph with 5 vertices---call them `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, `v4`, `v5`---the graph can be represented by your matrix.

```
     v1   v2   v3   v4   v5
v1   0.0  1.8  9.1  4.0  3.5 
v2   1.8  0.0  8.1  5.2  8.6 
v3   9.1  8.1  0.0  2.9  8.1 
v4   4.0  5.2  2.9  0.0  2.0 
v5   3.5  8.6  8.1  2.0  0.0
```

The number in, say, `(v2, v4)`, represents an edge connecting `v2` and `v4` with a weight of `5.2`. The zero entry could represent non-edges, or edges with zero weight. Non-weighted graphs are usually represented with a boolean value in each entry, `1` representing an edge, `0` representing no edge. The graph is (well, can be) undirected if the matrix is symmetric.

NB: the picture in your question cannot be represented by the given matrix: the matrix represents a graph with 5 vertices, and the graph represented by the picture has 8 vertices.

Comment: Yeah I just googled a sample tree for the sake of the question haha, but this answers it perfectly! Thanks heaps <3

Answer (score 1):

A 2D array (=matrix) is a common way to represent a graph. It is also called [Adjacency Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

> In graph theory, an adjacency matrix is a square
>   matrix used to represent a finite graph. The elements of the matrix
>   indicate whether pairs of vertices are adjacent or not in the graph.

A matrix `M` that is `NxN` represents a graph with `N` vertices (nodes).
When `M[i][j] = 0` there is no edge between vertices `i` and `j`.
When `M[i][j] = 1` there exist an edge between vertices `i` and `j`.

Sometimes it is easy to have a different number than `1` to represent the weight of this specific edge (same as in your case).

Comment: Hi and how does that answer his question and solve his problem? There are no `1`s in his table, hence your answer is a little random.

Comment: I think it helps, there's no 1's, but instead of 1's I have my weights

Comment: @FirstStep He asked "The values represent the weights but then what represents the nodes and edges?" I think my answer is covering it.